# Jaeger Operator for Openshift trouble with the guide

Tags: openshift, jaeger

Following [this](https://github.com/jaegertracing/jaeger-operator) guide I I don't really see how to implement the operator with elasticsearch.

Ok, so I install the operator and after that follwing the  example which is with :

```
apiVersion: jaegertracing.io/v1
```

which is not supported by openshift as an api.

I just need to deploy jeager operator for with 1 elasticsearch, but this guide is quite confusing. Does anyone know a quick and easy guide on how to do it?

Comment: What document did you read for jaeger-operator installation ?

Comment: Sorry,  I added the link. I thaught I pasted it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you install the operator on openshift using the instructions listed: https://github.com/jaegertracing/jaeger-operator#openshift ?

Did the operator start up ok, if you not were there errors in the log?

The [Creating a new Jaeger Instance](https://github.com/jaegertracing/jaeger-operator#creating-a-new-jaeger-instance) section starts with a link to some examples, including [simple-prod.yaml](https://github.com/jaegertracing/jaeger-operator/blob/master/deploy/examples/simple-prod.yaml), which creates a Jaeger instance that uses an Elasticsearch cluster at the specified URL.

You simply run:

```
oc create -f simple-prod.yaml
```